# How to resolve occasional input lag in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2023.2.3, and sometimes when I input a "#" or a space, or press Enter, it lags for about a second, and then it becomes smooth. If I switch to other windows and then return to the PyCharm interface, the input experiences the lag as mentioned earlier.

Initially, I was using SSH to connect to a Conda virtual environment on a server, and the code automatically synchronized to the server. I thought it might be the issue, but even after setting up the environment locally, the lag issue persists.

That's the basic situation.

My CPU is an i5 13490F.

Want to make pycharm smoother...

Comment: try to reinstall it